# Simple Residue calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

$$\int_{\gamma(0;2)}\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z^2-1} \, dz$$
Using the residue calculus i got $$-2\pi$$But the answer is $$=i$$ I must be wrong at this, but shouldn't the answer have $\pi$ at least since the integral already requires $2\pi i \cdot\text{residue }$?

Comment: [Read'em and weep](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Residue%5BExp%5BI*Pi*z%2F2%5D%2F%28z%5E2-1%29%2C%7Bz%2C-1%7D%5D). So you are correct.

Comment: How should we interpret the notation $\gamma(0;2)$?

Comment: it is the circle centered at 0 with radius 2. Hence, +1 and -1 is inside the contour.

Comment: You have two poles inside the contour.

Comment: @science definitely. and they are simple.

Comment: You need to use partial fraction and things will be straightforward.

Comment: It's probably just a typo and you should suspect this since the sum of the residues is exactly $i$ which when multiplied by $2\pi i$ yields the integral.

Comment: @science the example is using such strategy, obtaining the right answer. but I would think that residue would be easier...

Comment: @GitGud the calculation was using partial fractions, which made sense, and getting the answer = i

Comment: @rebc It's $-2\pi$. If you want people to spot the error in the partial fractions solution, you should post the proposed solution.

Comment: The mistake in the partial fraction solution is that the $2\pi i$ factor from Cauchy's Integral Formula is missing.

Comment: @GitGud oooohhhh haha how stupid am I. but anyway thats on Preistley, complex analysis p.153.  It wasnt even stated as a correction. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Gid Gut's commentary : we have $$\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}z}}{z^{2}-1}=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}z}}{\left(z+1\right)\left(z-1\right)}
 $$ thus there are two simple poles at $z=\pm1
 $. Then by the residue theorem, we get $$\oint_{\gamma\left(0,2\right)}\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}z}}{z^{2}-1}dz=2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}}{2}-\frac{e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}}{2}\right)=2\pi i\left(i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-2\pi
 $$

Comment: i think it should be $$=2\pi i i sin (\pi/2) =  -2\pi$$

Comment: Oh yes, sorry : I will fix it. But the answer is not $i$ (hope you are convinced anyway!).